# Non-linearity of viscosity solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, viscosity-solutions

I am interested in the following problem.

Let consider the solution of the non-linear PDE on $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}$ satifying the following Cauchy problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t = F(u_{xx}),\\
u(0,x) = u_0(x).
\end{cases}
$$
Let suppose that $F$ is uniformly elliptic and assume that $u_0$ is not linear on all non-empty intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ ***(i)***. Is it true that for all $t\in[0,T]$, the function $x\mapsto u(t,x)$ is not linear on all non-empty intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Any hint or references will be highly appreciated !

***(i)** : What I mean is that, you cannot find $a>b$ such that $u_0$ is linear on $[a,b]$.*

Thank you very much.